# Set event handlers in styles

Tags: xaml, win-universal-app

In WPF, we can easily set event handlers using `EventSetter` inside `Style`s. How come it's not ported to Universal Windows Apps? And how to work around this limitation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use instead the `EventTriggerBehavior` part of the [Behaviors SDK](http://www.timmykokke.com/2013/09/behaviors-sdk/), which now comes built into Visual Studio 2013,

[image: Behavior SDK]

```
<Button Content="Click" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" >
        <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
               <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="Click">
                  <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ClickCommand}" CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
               </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
        </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
</Button>
```

Comment: Should it be applied to controls directly? Or can it be used in styles?

Comment: Is it recommended to use this SDK in Universal Windows Apps? It targets Windows 8.1 WinRT ...

Comment: Yes, since they are well supported and maintained

Answer (score 0):

Now in Windows universal app, you can download the behaviours as nuget package.
https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed/

Source : 
https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2015/11/30/xaml-behaviors-open-source-and-on-uwp/